# Uniswap v2 swap() function. What are balance0 & balance1?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap

I'm learning how the Uniswapv2 contracts work but I can't seem to wrap my mind around the `swap()` function.

Reference: https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol#L173

Lines 173-174 contain:

```
balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
```

My question is, when & whose balances are these?

A. These are the same as `_reserve0` & `_reserve1` after the most recent swap and will be used to synchronize reserves.

B. These are the quantities of each token the user making the swap currently possesses.

C. None of the above. It's something else. Please explain the flow of this function. I cannot find a clear and concise definition anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is "C" :)

`balanceOf` is a mapping in `ERC20` implementation  to return the amount that given address holds:

```
 // address => holds uint amount
 mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;
```

Since current contract is inheriting from `UniswapV2ERC20`:

```
contract UniswapV2Pair is IUniswapV2Pair, UniswapV2ERC20{}
```

it can access to [UniswapV2ERC20.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2ERC20.sol)

Since the mapping `balanceOf` is public, solidity assigns getters to the public variables

In the functions:

```
balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
```

`address(this)` refers to the current contract which is `UniswapV2Pair`. So `balance0` is how much the current contract owns `_token0` and `balance1` is how much the current contract address owns `_token1`. `token0` and `token1` are contract addresses and each `ERC20` token contract, keeps track of addresses and their balances. so you are visiting each token contract and getting how much balance the current contract has.

Think `ERC20` contract like a bank. you have `token0` bank and `token1` bank. Each bank keeps track of the balances of their users. `balancesOf` is where `ERC20` tokens store those balances. Your current contract also owns some of those tokens so you just want to get how much tokens the current contract holds

`swap` function will be called by the user. Before executing the swap, contract checks if it has enough funds

```
uint amount0In = balance0 > _reserve0 - amount0Out ? balance0 - (_reserve0 - amount0Out) : 0;
uint amount1In = balance1 > _reserve1 - amount1Out ? balance1 - (_reserve1 - amount1Out) : 0;
require(amount0In > 0 || amount1In > 0, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
```

Comment: Current contract meaning, the Pair contract AKA, the pool quantities of each token stored in this pair. But what are reserves if not the same?

Comment: I can explain but it will be a deep dive into how uniswap code flow works and the answer will be bloated, long, and confusing. you should ask a separate question

Comment: I've been reading about uniswapv2 for a week. I guess what I'm asking is, mathematically, what are balance0 & balance1? Feel free to revise this answer. Most of it can be found here https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/uniswap-v2-annotated-code/

Comment: `token0` and `token1` are contract addresses and each ERC20 token contract, keeps track of addresses and their balances. so you are visiting each token contract and getting how much balance current contract has.

Comment: So I'm visiting the balances of the real tokens, NOT the address of the token mapped to a reserve inside uniswap, correct?

Comment: Looks like you have studied alot. I can see the side effects of uniswap studying :) i feel like you studied uniswap before studying erc20. I ll try to visualize the situation

Comment: Hahaha! You've read my mind. I have... I should have gone the other way around for now obvious reasons.

Comment: Think ERC20 contract like a bank. you have token0 bank and token1 bank. Each bank keeps track of the balances of their users. balancesOf is where ERC20 tokens store those balances. Your current contract also owns some of those tokens so you just want to get how much tokens the current contract holds